# tenshi and logfiles

Tags: logs, monitoring

I'm about to set up [Tenshi](http://www.inversepath.com/tenshi.html) in order to get important log excerpts.
Everything works fine except if I add some apache2 logs,

```
# /etc/tenshi/tenshi.conf

...
set logfile /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

I also created a Tenshi include for `apache2`, but it doesn't work.

```
# /etc/tenshi/includes-active/apache2

group ^apache2:

trash ^apache2: \[client \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\] client denied by server configuration:
trash ^apache2: \[client \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\] Directory index forbidden by Options directive:

group_end
```

**Question:** What is wrong with the config and how to create an include for non standard logs?

Comment: what do you mean by "It doesn't work?"

Comment: The `apache2` group define that the `trash` lines should be discarded in the report. Tenshi seems to understand  only logs created by syslogd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed this:

In `tenshi.conf` use:

```
set logprefix ^(\[[^\]]+\]\s)
```

This prevents the parsed logfiles from reaching the `noprefix` queue.

My apache2 error logfile looks like this:

```
[Thu Jan 23 23:36:40 2014] [error] [client 255.255.255.255] File does not exist: /var/www/whatever.html
```

So in `includes-active/apache2` you need to have the same regex i.e.

```
group ^\[[^\]]+\]\s

trash \[error\].*?  File does not exist:

group_end
```

Thank you guys, close but no cigar.

Answer (score 3):

`tenshi` is just a Perl script so you can modify it in any way that you want. To show you what's going on when you run your commands you could make use of `tenshi`'s pretty useful debugging features.

#### My Apache's error_log

I brought my Apache's `error_log` into the same directory as `tenshi`, and modified `tenshi.conf` file to run as me and use the local directory.

```
##
## tenshi 0.14 sample conf
##

# general settings

set uid saml
set gid saml

set pidfile /home/saml/tenshi/tenshi-0.14/tenshi.pid
set logfile /home/saml/tenshi/tenshi-0.14/error_log
...
...
critical ^\[client.*
# ^^^^--- above line matches this ---vvvvv
# [client 74.221.219.48] script '/home/httpd/html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://ww
```

#### A test run

Now when I run it, the following output is produced:

```
$ ./tenshi -f -d 2 -c tenshi.conf
```

[image: ss #1]

Also in my `tenshi.conf` file was this line:

```
set queue noprefix tenshi@localhost sysadmin@localhost [now] tenshi unprefixed alert
```

Having this line was catching my rule and acting on it, in this case it was attempting to email me the above message.

[image: ss #2]

#### Tenshi's logprefix

If I set the configuration option per the [tenshi documentation](http://www.inversepath.com/tenshi_man.html):

```
set logprefix \[client
```

I now get the messages from my Apache `error_log` logged as expected.

```
[MAIN]  got message: [client 192.3.183.22] script '/home/httpd/html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/wp-content/plugins/cleaner-gallery/readme.html
[MAIN]  got message: [client 188.247.132.250] script '/home/httpd/html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://www.lamolabs.org/
[MAIN]  got message: [client 188.247.132.250] script '/home/httpd/html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://www.lamolabs.org/
[MAIN]  got message: [client 188.247.132.250] script '/home/httpd/html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://www.lamolabs.org/
[MAIN]  got message: [client 192.95.43.193] script '/home/httpd/html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/date/2010/03/page/2/
[MAIN]  got message: [client 88.245.191.59] script '/home/httpd/html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[MAIN]  got message: [client 88.245.191.59] script '/home/httpd/html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
```

#### EDIT #1

I was unsuccessful in figuring out how to do the `trash` like yourself. So I sent an email to Inversepath inquiring how one would go about doing this.

[image: ss of email]

#### EDIT #2

Bersh cracked the trick with this setup. You have to wrap the `logprefix` in parenthsis, like this:

```
set logprefix ^(\[client)
...
trash  ^\[client.*
```

Now when I re-run `tenshi` I get output that shows it's detecting the logs from my Apache `error_log`.

[image: ss of working output]

#### A group example

If we want to filter out a group patterns that come from `error_log` we'd wrap our rules using the same `logprefix` regex.

```
set logprefix ^(\[client)
...
group ^(\[client)
trash ^.*not found or unable to stat, referer: http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/6194/.*
trash ^.*not found or unable to stat, referer: http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/wp-content/plugins/.*
group_end
```

Now when we run `tenshi` again we get this output.

[image: ss #1]

[image: ss #2]

In the above output we can see that the `trash` rules in our `group ^(\[client)` are being matched (they're the red lines), and they're masking the contents of those lines.

Comment: Thanks. I still dont get it. I got managed to get the output you showed, but what should contain the `/etc/tenshi/includes-active/apache2` file in order to trash those messages?

Comment: @bersch - I couldn't figure it out either, I ran the Perl program through the Perl debugger and can see what it's doing. It seems to be hardcoded to expecting the first argument in the log to be a hostname, but it was unclear to be if that was what was tripping it up. At any rate, I sent them an email inquiring about it.

Comment: great, I appreciate it.

Comment: @bersch - since I sunk so much time into this issue I've updated my A with your findings. I've included a screenshot so that hopefully any poor souls that have this issue in the future will hopefully stumble across this and save their time 8-). Thanks for the Q btw, never used this app before, might consider trying it out in the future!

Comment: Since your answer was closest you are the bounty winner. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @bersch - thanks, I tried very hard, it was a perplexing problem, thank you, and thanks for asking the Q, keep 'em coming 8-)

Comment: @bersch - I actually got a reply from inversepath about this issue. I've sent a reply for clarification, I'll add any additional findings to my A.

Answer (score 2):

`tenshi` by default only checks *syslog* style files, and discards log-files that do not match these.

here's the relevant excerpt from the [`tenshi` documentation](http://www.inversepath.com/tenshi_man.html):

> `set logprefix <regexp>`
>
> All valid syslog messages are parsed by default, while non-syslog ones
>   are discarded unless the special `noprefix` queue is set. This option
>   allows to define an additional valid prefix for watching other type of
>   logs. If the regexp is matched then the prefix is removed from the log
>   and the first grouped string is used for the hostname field. This may
>   be specified multiple times to watch many different non-syslog logs.

so the solution is to use the `noprefix` queue for your *apache2* logfiles.

an alternative would be to make [apache use syslog](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+syslog) for logging...

Comment: could you provide a working example.